# extract values from td tags in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where I have to gather information from a webpage. I need to extract anything encapsulated td tags of the HTML tables

In this particular situation the only thing I have available to do this process is PowerShell.

Is there an easy way to do this only using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to main options:

1. Use a regular expression.
2. Use the DOM.

Here's how you can do both:

Regex:

```
$data = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://www.amazon.com')
[regex]::Matches($data, '<td.*?>(.+)</td>') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
```

DOM:

```
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate('http://www.amazon.com')
$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('td')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  thank you so much for your assistance.  Andy Arismendi.  I used the Regex version

Answer (score 0):

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("<app url>")
$doc = $ie.Document
$doc.getElementByID("<some id>")
```

You may read here for more information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx

Hope this helps.